# OleContainer - Opening a doc file from http?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2010

I need some info about OleContainer. I embedded an OleContainer in the browser. And when I launch that html file,a microsoft word OleContainer is opened and I want to display content of a doc file from the web. For example, when I open  html file, OleContainer should view the content of the www.example.com/example.doc which is a doc file inside of it.I hope I clearly explained the problem. Thx for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a OleContainer? Objects can be embedded in HTML using the standard HTML `<object>` tag. See for example

- [embed content in valid strict HTML](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/)
- [Embed a MS Office document in HTML webpage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/03736117-fc0f-4232-9c14-2aef79db83da/)

This has also the advantage that it is cross-platform (as long as the document type is known on the client computer).

Answer (score 0):

You need download the file from http-server (using sockets or WinInet library) to temporary directory and load to TOLEContainer using CreateObjectFromFile method